# How to Display All the Images from Json Data into Carousal using Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I have an Json API which has set of Data along with Multiple Images, I would like to Create an Carousal and Display all the images from the json data in flutter[image: Json Data]

Answer (score 0):

You can use carousel_slider for carousel and for images u can use Image.network or Cached network image

Answer (score 0):

You should always try to include in your question what you have already attempted and what specific problems you're facing, however it's quite a straightforward answer so here's the gist of how to do it.

You can get your raw API data using the http package and a `get` request. Once you have this, you can decode it using `jsonDecode(String data)`, which returns a `Map<String, dynamic>`. You can then select the list field as in any map object (`jsonMap['images']`) and use the list `.map` method to create a list of `Image.network` widgets to use as the `children` in you carousel package of choice (or build your own).